# Pypyodbc with oracle 11gR2 throwing SQL_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g, odbc, pypyodbc

I'm using pypyodbc-1.3.3 to connect to oracle DB. I'm doing

```
 pypyodbc.connect('Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}; DBQ=TNSNAME; uid=TESTUSER; pwd=TESTP;')
```

I'm getting
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('', 'SQL_INVALID_HANDLE')

I'm not able to resolve the issue.

Note: My TNS_ADMIN is setup to my current directory where tnsnames.ora file is present.

I've also tried using "SERVER" instead of "DBQ". Please help!